# Execute set of tasks in parallel but with a group timeout

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm currently trying to write a status checking tool with a reliable timeout value.  One way I'd seen how to do this was using Task.WhenAny() and including a Task.Delay, however it doesn't seem to produce the results I expect:

```
public void DoIUnderstandTasksTest()
{
      var checkTasks = new List<Task>();

      // Create a list of dummy tasks that should just delay or "wait"
      // for some multiple of the timeout
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
          checkTasks.Add(Task.Delay(_timeoutMilliseconds/2));
      }

      // Wrap the group of tasks in a task that will wait till they all finish
      var allChecks = Task.WhenAll(checkTasks);

      // I think WhenAny is supposed to return the first task that completes
      bool didntTimeOut = Task.WhenAny(allChecks, Task.Delay(_timeoutMilliseconds)) == allChecks;

      Assert.True(didntTimeOut);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What results does it produce? "Doesn't work" is a very general term and hard for us to know what's wrong. Exception? Compilation error? Never returns from the second WhenAll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confusing the workings of the `When...` calls with `Wait...`.

`Task.WhenAny` doesn't return the first task to complete among those you pass to it. Rather, it returns a *new* Task that will be completed when *any* of the internal tasks finish. This means your equality check will always return false - the new task will never equal the previous one.

The behavior you're expecting seems similar to `Task.WaitAny`, which will *block* current execution until any of the internal tasks complete, and return the *index* of the completed task. 
Using WaitAny, your code will look like this:

```
    // Wrap the group of tasks in a task that will wait till they all finish
  var allChecks = Task.WhenAll(checkTasks);
  var taskIndexThatCompleted = Task.WaitAny(allChecks, Task.Delay(_timeoutMilliseconds));

  Assert.AreEqual(0, taskIndexThatCompleted);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick accurate response